# qtsql: Query inserts malformed UTF-8 text to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, qt, pyqt, qtsql

I want to connect to my MySQL database and insert some UTF8 strings. But when I do the `insert` query, some text like `Ø³Ø³Ø³Ø³Ø³Ø³Ø³Ø³Ø³Ø³Ø³Ø³Ø³Ø³Ø³Ø³` is inserted into my table.

This is my code:

```
s = QtCore.QString("insert into test4 values(''  , ' شسشس')");
self.onlineQuery.exec_(s);
```

What's wrong with my query?

Edit:

I solved the problem with this code:

```
QtCore.QTextCodec.setCodecForCStrings(QtCore.QTextCodec.codecForName("UTF-8"))
QtCore.QTextCodec.setCodecForLocale ( QtCore.QTextCodec.codecForName("UTF-8"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the connection charset is set to UTF-8. This is not always the default.